# Is it possible to diff a file from oldrev, and newrev, in a post-receive hook?

Tags: git

I have a script that sets up a server. In the script I generate a git hook that runs when I push to a bare repo (I use a push to deploy workflow).

In the hook I want to check if a specific file in the old revision has changed since the new revision. If so, run a specific command.

Is it possible to do this? The script I have created is below:

```
cat >$home/api.git/hooks/post-receive <<'ILOVEBASH'
#!/bin/bash

while read oldrev newrev ref
do
    if [[ $ref =~ .*/master$ ]];
    then
        echo "Master ref received:  Deploying ..."
        git --work-tree=$webroot --git-dir=$home/api.git/ checkout -f

        # If the /composer.json file in the oldrev differs from newrev
            # Do something ...

    else
        echo "Only the master branch may be deployed on this server."
    fi
done
ILOVEBASH
```

Answer (score 2):

It is possible, and even easy.

First, though, this is the wrong way to test the ref:

> ```
> if [[ $ref =~ .*/master$ ]];
> ```

because that means that if I send you `refs/heads/not/master` you'll think I've sent you branch `master` when I've actually sent you branch `not/master`.  If you really want to test for `master`, test for `refs/heads/master`, not `.*/master`:

```
if [ "$ref" = refs/heads/master ];
```

This is also probably wrong:

> ```
> else [...complain...]; fi
> ```

This will, for instance, complain every time you push a *tag*.  (It's kind of harmless since it only gripes, rather than stopping the push.)

Now, to compare two files, just run `git diff` on them.  Or rather, run `git diff-tree`, restricted to those two files, with additional options such as `-p` for a patch:

```
git diff-tree -p $oldrev $newrev -- composer.json
```

The reason to use `git diff-tree` is that its behavior is predictable and hence testable everywhere.  The `git diff` front end obeys configuration entries, which could change from one repository to another based on user settings.

The output from `git diff-tree` tells you what changed.  When you *don't* use `-p`, the output is particularly convenient if you only want to know if something changed.  I ran these in a shell, not from a hook, so I used `HEAD^` and `HEAD` rather than `$oldrev` and `$newrev`, but the output should be pretty self-explanatory:

```
$ git diff-tree HEAD^ HEAD -- Documentation/RelNotes/2.20.1.txt
:040000 040000 12fe36dc6cb8966bfa24b832fe2d3d78cce152b5 04a4194134826e9a84a513a79a1b9f8f428f7f5d M      Documentation
```

If the file is not in the top level (as is the case in my example, but not in yours) you probably want `-r`:

```
$ git diff-tree -r HEAD^ HEAD -- Documentation/RelNotes/2.20.1.txt
:000000 100644 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 dcba888dba4d12d745a796de39b45b4c9a0497b5 A      Documentation/RelNotes/2.20.1.txt
```

and of course you can eliminate the file names to find *what* changed:

```
$ git diff-tree -r HEAD^ HEAD
:000000 100644 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 dcba888dba4d12d745a796de39b45b4c9a0497b5 A      Documentation/RelNotes/2.20.1.txt
:100755 100755 216beefc50d54d132991636d5f049ea0916f1696 d1a2814ec7e415a525e58ac234df8184a2d0f93c M      GIT-VERSION-GEN
:120000 120000 8d0b1654d25536f72abe885634c36412ae8b3246 463a237c65db66593e317d55103a6212a095b8aa M      RelNotes
```

though for testing a single file, as in your case, this is all overkill.